# What is the easiest way to free space on a hard drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, debian, disk-space

My hard drive became full. I am looking for ways to locate the things that use most of my disk space. I played with cron once so it may have consumed a great deal of space, but really I have no clue.

I have backed up my things to CDs, but the system is still getting too slow. Perhaps I should reinstall everything, but whilst fixing the problem it doesn't address the cause.

### Testing KamilMaciorowski's answer for `ncdu`

I run `ncdu` as `root` and get the following where I missed out the backup file in my system by other methods

```
--- /home/masi ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   45.5GiB [##########]  backup_home_1.9.2016.tar.gz
   34.9GiB [#######   ] /Documents                                                                                                                                                                                 
    1.4GiB [          ] /Videos
    1.4GiB [          ] /.cache
    1.2GiB [          ] /Downloads
    1.0GiB [          ] /.config
  607.8MiB [          ] /Pictures
  487.0MiB [          ] /.matlab
  447.2MiB [          ] /Images
  406.1MiB [          ] /Desktop
   97.1MiB [          ] /.kingsoft
   58.4MiB [          ] /.local
   20.6MiB [          ] /.Mathematica
   13.3MiB [          ] /.mozilla
   ...
```

Comment: 1. You should really specify the OS for which you are looking tools and suggestions. (though seeing your username might be enough of an answer :-))
2. I have the sneaky suspicion that this question will be closed as "Not programming related"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux tool `ncdu` is very convenient in my opinion. It's like interactive `du`.

### Some features

- Text interface (`ncurses`); works via SSH, no Xserver needed.
- Still you can move within directory tree to find large dirs/files quickly.
- You can delete dir/file from within the program.

### Screenshot

Well, kind of. There's no point in pasting picture, text will be enough:

```
ncdu 1.10 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                    
--- / --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    6,7GiB [##########] /usr
    3,4GiB [#####     ] /var
  553,1MiB [          ] /lib
  529,1MiB [          ] /opt
   35,1MiB [          ] /etc
   32,5MiB [          ] /home_old                                               
   16,4MiB [          ] /sbin
    9,9MiB [          ] /bin
    8,2MiB┌───ncdu help─────────────────1:Keys───2:Format───3:About──┐
    3,8MiB│                                                          │
    1,3MiB│       up, k  Move cursor up                              │
  500,0KiB│     down, j  Move cursor down                            │
  124,0KiB│ right/enter  Open selected directory                     │
   12,0KiB│  left, <, h  Open parent directory                       │
    8,0KiB│           n  Sort by name (ascending/descending)         │
@   4,0KiB│           s  Sort by size (ascending/descending)         │
@   4,0KiB│           C  Sort by items (ascending/descending)        │
@   4,0KiB│           d  Delete selected file or directory           │
    0,0  B│           t  Toggle dirs before files when sorting       │
>   0,0  B│           g  Show percentage and/or graph                │
e   0,0  B│                        -- more --                        │
>   0,0  B│                                     Press q to continue  │
>   0,0  B└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
>   0,0  B [          ] /home
>   0,0  B [          ] /dev
e   0,0  B [          ] /cpusets
e   0,0  B [          ] /cdrom
>   0,0  B [          ] /boot



 Total disk usage:  11,3GiB  Apparent size:  11,1GiB  Items: 289029
```

### Usage:

```
ncdu -x /foo/bar/mountpoint
```

Use `sudo` (and caution!) when necessary. The `-x` option is important, it makes `ncdu` stay within single filesystem (`du` has the same option). In the example (above) my `/home` is on a different partition than `/` where `ncdu` started, therefore it does not count – thanks to `-x` switch exactly.

Comment: This tool is very powerful! Thank you very much for pointing it out! It finds easily culprits in my system; those which I did not find by my systematic way because it is so easy to miss things in big systems.

Answer (score 7):

"I played with cron once so it may have consumed my mass memory, but really I have no clue."
No clue, you say?  never would have guessed. :)

```
su -
cd /
du -s ./* | sort -n
```

- `du` shows disk usage, in blocks (1 block = 0.5 kilobytes, in all cases that matter to you.)
- `-s` means, "summary", so it gives only a total for each argument "./*" being the argument.
- piping it into `sort -n` means sort numerically.  The larger numbers at the bottom.
- So, you'll get a list of directories with the ones using the most space at the bottom.

If that's not enough help, say you get:

```
60380   ./root
142468  ./etc
537716  ./var
627264  ./lib
5757600 ./usr
28859472        ./home
```

- and you see that ./home is the biggest piggy, 
  ok, `cd` into /home, and do the same `du -s | sort -n`.  Then you see who in /home is taking up space.  (on a single user system, well, it's probably you.)
- Then cd into there, and do `du -s | sort -n` again.

Keep doing this until you find the culprit.  When you find the culprit, you may say, oh yeah... that's my collection of hi-res renderings of Romulan Birds of Prey for my star trek RPG game that I'm building, so yeah, of course that takes up a lot of space, or you may say, of course that takes up a lot of space, so let's rm -fr that bad boy.

Magic words to remember:

```
du -s | sort -n
```

Answer (score 7):

[KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) is another option which will help you identify large files and directories.

[image]

I've used the Windows clone WinDirStat a lot and it is an awesome tool.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Disk Usage Analyzer, you can find it in Programs -> Accessories, it will analyze the disk usage and show it as a diagram to you.

Also, remove unnecessary programs and clear out the old package cache by running `sudo apt-get clean` .

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Bobby's last point, run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

…to clear out all extra packages and unneeded install files. Also, it would be a really good idea to go through your applications and remove the ones you don’t use any more.

Comment: I added an example about your command in the body. I really like your `autoclean`. Actually, I have never used it before intentionally. It really saved many MBs from my SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Per the "Linux Server Hacks" by O'Reilly

`alias ducks='du -cks * | sort -rn | head -11'`

Then go to any directory and run the alias

Comment: I would use `du -cksh` to get the sizes in MB/GB!

Answer (score 0):

Software built-in: *Disk Usage Analyzer*. 
Fig. 1 Polar coordinate view of masi's `/`, 
Fig. 2 Rectangular view of masi's `/` where you move your mouse to visualize contents

[image] 
[image]

Delete things which you do not need then

1. manually after inspection carefully
2. clean packages in `apt-get`

   ```
   # http://superuser.com/a/113904/2005
   su 
   apt-get autoclean
   ```

   - Example output in my Asus Zenbook UX303UA where I use the Linux kernel backports (currently 4.6)

     ```
     root@masi:/home/masi# apt-get autoclean
     Reading package lists... Done
     Building dependency tree       
     Reading state information... Done
     Del chromium 53.0.2785.89-1~deb8u1 [42.0 MB]
     Del chromium 52.0.2743.116-1~deb8u1 [41.3 MB]
     Del libtomcat7-java 7.0.56-3+deb8u3 [3,623 kB]
     Del mysql-common 5.5.50-0+deb8u1 [81.8 kB]
     Del libmysqlclient18 5.5.50-0+deb8u1 [675 kB]
     Del libservlet3.0-java 7.0.56-3+deb8u3 [314 kB]
     Del linux-libc-dev 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 [1,025 kB]
     ```
3. Remove unused packages if you do not have dependency problems

   ```
   apt-get autoremove
   ```
4. ...

There are also tools which try to find duplicate files in your system

- use merge and diff tools too to find duplicates in directories
- `fdupes`, however, can delete wrong files so I am not using it anymore
- ...

If you have an updated working tree and you want to replace an old one in your other system

1. Use `rsync` by knowing your case precisely because it is sharp - can be efficient or work against you if you do not know what you are doing

   - [To rsync -rtvuc in Two Filesystems?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287007/16920)
   - ...

OS: Debian 8.5
Window manager: Gnome 3.14