# How to check the directory size using find command?

Tags: linux, find, du

I would like to list the directories which is having size more than 10MB. I tried the same using `find` command but `find` command is not giving result with size and type option. It is working with any of type or size option.

I tried these commands:

- `find /opt -type d` - working
- `du -sh /opt/test` - it is 20MB
- `find /opt -size +10M` - listed `/opt/test/file1`
- `find /opt -type f -size +10M` - listed `/opt/test/file1`
- `find /opt -type d -size +10M` - This command is not showing any output.

`find` command is not working with `-type d` and `-size` options together. Can anyone suggest me a solution to achieve my requirement?

Comment: I suspect this is an XY problem - why do you need to use find?  I might be inclined to use "du" with the -t parameter rather then find. I guess if I was bloody minded I could make it work as an exec option of find...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A directory is also a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690), it has its own size which is not the total size of files within. It makes even more sense when you are able to read a directory like a regular file, but nowadays [it's not that common](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154119/108618).

If you run `stat` on a directory then you will see the size I'm talking about. It's not that `find` command does not work with `-type d` and `-size` option together. It does work, only the size tested with `-size` is not what you want.

On the other hand `du` is deliberately designed to sum space allocated to all files in the directory:

> The size of the file space allocated to a file of type directory shall be defined as the sum total of space allocated to all files in the file hierarchy rooted in the directory plus the space allocated to the directory itself.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html))</sup>

To find all directories for which `du` returns a number great enough, you can build a custom test in `find` that will actually run `du` and parse its output:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
      result="$(du -sk "$1" | tr "\t" " ")"
      result="${result%% *}"
      [ "$result" -gt 10240 ]
   ' find-sh {} \; -print
```

Notes:

- POSIX requires `du` to separate the number and the pathname with one space character. Still GNU `du` in my Debian 10 uses the tab character (even if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set). This is the reason I used `tr` to convert tab characters to spaces. Tab characters (if any) in the pathname printed by `du` are also converted, but it doesn't matter because this part of the line is discarded anyway.
- POSIX `du` without `-k` uses units of 512 bytes. Implementations may use different defaults and various options/ways to specify the unit. Explicitly imposing `-k` seems right; this option is required by POSIX, it should be widely supported and unambiguous.
- `find-sh` is explained here: [What is the second `sh` in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)
- The code may be sub-optimal. My main concern was to make it portable.
- Here `-exec` is a test. You can add more tests and/or actions before (or instead of) `-print`.

---

If all you need is to *know* big directories (rather than to parse the information further in some automated way, or to perform additional tests), then this may be enough:

```
du -k . | sort -n
```

Next you need to manually filter the result (compare to the threshold) and pick zero or more last entries. Pathnames containing newline characters will misbehave, still occasional newlines probably won't compromise the entire result, especially if you inspect it with insight, not mechanically.

Your `du` may support `-t`/`--threshold` option which can do the filtering for you; but the option is not portable.

---

If interactively, use [`ncdu`](https://superuser.com/a/1125862/432690).